# How I can get the name and path to choosed image after uploaded?

Tags: laravel, image, image-uploading

I have a problem with getting of uploaded image, because when I posted my form with picture, after reloading of page the input asked to choose the file again, how I can get choosed image? So If I will post this form again, It will be empty, because I did not choose file

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 my_form">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label  ">Picture</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="picture" accept=".jpeg, .png, .jpg">
                            <img src="{{picture}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you make it more clear why you need to submit the form more than one time?

Comment: @HussamAdil For example: CREATE PROFILE with photo, some times later I want to change name of user, and when I submit the PHOTO value will null, because I do not to choose new photo

Comment: I think we should tell laravel If image is not empty put the rules otherwise do nothing.
`$this->validate($request, [
    'image' => 'sometimes|nullable',
]);`
for more read [https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#conditionally-adding-rules]

Comment: Yeah I thought about it but if I want that my profile will withought photo?

Comment: your image profile is nullable or required?

Comment: @HussamAdil Nullable, so sometimes I need a photo sometimes not

Comment: you need the image if the user selected or if the user has no profile image? so when you need the image?

Comment: @HussamAdil I need image when I want, not everytimes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203891/discussion-between-aleks-and-hussam-adil).

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the `$image == null` then it will require the image but if the `$image != null` just display the uploaded image and don't require the input.

In your controller remove the `required` validation.

```
$request->validate([
            'name'              =>  'required',
            'profile_image'     =>  'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048'
        ]);
```

In this code it will not overwrite the image with `null`.

Comment: Thank you, but It is not true solution. If I reload page, I need that will choosed file and not to choose again

Comment: Can you post the snippet of your template?

Comment: I changed my post

Comment: @Aleks I also need to know the controller in `store` and `index` or `show`

Comment: Controller is like here https://www.larashout.com/laravel-image-upload-made-easy

Comment: I updated my code. It will error because the request was validated and profile_image is null so it will not save the updated user

Comment: Sorry, but I think you did not understand my question. My code is complete -good. But how I can get path after reload? Example: WHEN WE TYPE NAME: alice, after reloading page name stayed ALICE. But if I choosed file and reload page the file path is NULL so HOW I CAN GET FILE PATH AFTER RELOADING PAGE

Comment: I need a snippet of the controller that returns the view of the form. How did you get the `$picture` data

Comment: My controller is absolutely the same like  larashout.com/laravel-image-upload-made-easy

Comment: I think you need to change your `src` attribute to `{{ asset(auth()->user()->image) }}`

Comment: Yeah, I did it. But it is only to show image and after submit it will be empty because I will not new picture